# How I can access the classes in a project from another and vice versa?

Tags: java, netbeans

I have two projects in netbeans A and B.
I want to access classes from A Project to B Project A. So I'm going to Properties-> libraries-> Add Project and add the B project  to dependency of A project .

Is there a way to access classes from  B project to A project without getting "can't add cyclic references" error?

Thanks.

Comment: Without the full code I can't understand anything.

Comment: So these are two separate projects? Is the PracticaFina jar included as a library in SM.BAM.Biblioteca?

Comment: @whitlaaa yes it is  .

Comment: Does it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4595452/eclipse-share-code-among-multiple-projects answer your question?